# 2D unity platformer player movement question

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am trying to make a 2D unity platformer that shoots projectiles to the mouse direction.

so, i was trying to make the player move. but, there is a problem. it does not jump as i expected. when i pressed the jump key, sometimes, it jumps, but sometimes, it doesn't. and i think the jump doesn't usualy work while moving but i don't know how to fix this.

i tried putting the jump function into the if statement,changed variables, but it still doesn't work as i thought.

i used the sprite render to flip the sprite so the child objects does not flip with the player later in the game progress(because when i did it by vector and rotation at my first try, it didn't ended well)

```
public class playerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    //movement variables
    public float speed;
    private float moveInput;
        
    //player components
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRender;
   
    //jump variables
    private float jumpInput;
    public float jumpForce;

    //ground variables

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        spriteRender = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moving();
        jumping();
    }
    
    //move left & right function
    void moving()
    {
        moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if (moveInput > 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
            spriteRender.flipX = false;
        }
        else if (moveInput < 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
            spriteRender.flipX = true;
        }
    }

    //jump function
    void jumping()
    {
        //this input is what i tried for the jump function at the first
        //jumpInput = Input.GetAxis("Jump");
        //rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpInput * jumpForce);
        //but it fell down slowly so i made this line of code
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

He I had the same mistake. You just have to put "jumping()" in "Update()"!

Because if it is in the Fixedupdate it will only allow you to jump every second or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html
Alternatively, you could use rb.AddForce to make the character jump.